# placing website footer at minimal distance from top navigation bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want website footer to be pushed-down as the content increases, but if there is very less content,
the footer should appear in regular position (minimal distance from the website top navigation bar)
I donot want sticky footer. how to achive this?

Comment: css: margin-top:0px;

Comment: it only solves the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your content between them a minimum height.

So if your content area in the middle is called content, use .content { min-height: 600px;}

Make sure you apply heights to suit each screen size or some smaller devices may end up with a lot of unneeded white space.